# GP-WGANs with Minibatch Discrimination

Tags: neural-networks, generative-models

In the "[Improved Training of Wasserstein GANs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.00028.pdf)" paper the authors mentioned that [batch normalization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf) can **not** be used in combination with gradient penalty, since it introduces correlation between examples. Is the same statement true for [*minibatch discrimination*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.03498.pdf)?